# When adding a partition, should I expect to lose data or not?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I'm trying to understand what is meant by the wording of this Disk Utility cautionary message that appears when attempting to add a new partition to a disk.

```
Partitioning this device will delete the data stored on some of the partitions, 
and cannot be undone.

This partition will be added:

"Secondary"

This partition will be erased:

"Secondary"

This partition will be resized:

"Primary"
```

First point of confusion: It's going to be added and *then* erased?

Second point of confusion: Disk Utility is supposed to be able to add, resize, and delete partitions without losing data. Sources: [1](https://www.lifewire.com/disk-utility-add-delete-resize-existing-volumes-2260078), [2](https://www.techcityng.com/partition-mac-hard-drive-without-losing-data/) So why the ominous message, and who to believe?

### Update

I added a new partition and everything appears to have gone smoothly.
[An answer to another similar question](https://superuser.com/a/402632/567432) helped me to understand and decide to move forward with partitioning.

This guide, [How to Use macOS Sierra Disk Utility to Partition, Erase Drives](https://blog.macsales.com/38191-rocket-yard-guide-using-macos-sierra-disk-utility-to-partition-erase-drives) was also helpful.

Comment: If what you did solved your issue - please do not "update" your question with a "solved status."  Either upvote/accept the post that assisted you or write the answer yourself and mark it as "accepted."

Comment: @Allan I know, you're right. I just felt like what I wrote doesn't stand very well as an answer, since it's just a few links with little explanation. And the post that assisted me the most was an answer to a *different* question, which made this an awkward decision. I mostly added the "update" to let others know I had figured it out so they wouldn't waste their time trying to answer a solved problem. I will take a shot at composing a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Data should not be lost.
Just as Solar Mike said, do a backup if you can.

It creates a second partition, but the second will be empty, without any file system, so it will be erased to format it into the file system you choose.

Comment: I'd backup any important files before you do this, just in case things go bad.

Comment: Yes just in case you can, but he ask if the data will be erased, not if a problem appears

Comment: @Chris One of my friends believed the message that the data will be safe , then found it all gone... ALWAYS ALWAYS make an up to date backup before starting ANY partitioning task ... but it’s your data : your choice, just have a search through the site about the number of questions where data lost or drive wiped or partition unreadable occurrs...

Comment: Right, I never had a problem with my data during partitioning, but I edited my message to had the advice of making a backup.

Comment: @Chris I never lost my data either when partitioning, but always had a backup... which is partly why I have all my photos and ex-wife lost hers...

Answer (score 1):

No, most of the time it works just fine. Recently I wanted to partition my 2TB fusion drive into 4. But unfortunately "Disk Utility" was not responding and I had 500gb usable space and rest were gone!

Had to format the drive and then made the partitions and re-installed macOS.

Anything can happen anytime, ALWAYS back up your data first before adding a partition.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that there is a possibility of something going wrong during the partitioning process. But why does Apple phrase it with certainty: "partitioning this device *will* delete the data..." as if partitioning was meant to delete data by design, when that is not the case?

Comment: Not much you can do if you can't access the files before doing the partitioning. For me, the whole point of partitioning was so I could get access to files on an old HDD, which has Window 7 on it but does not open on Windows. It shows it has no partition

Answer (score 0):

For me, my first task would be the backup,

Then I would do the partitioning task - if it goes right no issue you have an up to date backup...

If it goes wrong - you have an up to date backup.

If you don’t do a backup and it goes wrong - your advantage is you have a lot more free space on your drive...